# Error on 'createSession' (OpenTok php sdk)

Tags: php, opentok, tokbox

I have a 'small' problem with OpenTok, making it impossible to use.

When I try to create a new session, the system just gets stuck. :(

I've pinpoint the problem to a function called '*createSession*', at  '*/OpenTok/Util/Client.php*'.

This is the function:

```
public function createSession($options)
{
    $request = new Request('POST', '/session/create');

try {
        $response = $this->client->send($request, [
            'debug' => $this->isDebug(),
            'form_params' => $this->postFieldsForOptions($options)
        ]);
    $sessionXml = $this->getResponseXml($response);
    } catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
        // TODO: test if we have a parse exception and handle it, otherwise throw again
        throw $e;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->handleException($e);
        return;
    }
    return $sessionXml;
}
```

And it gets stuck as soon as it tries to send the data to the *$response*.

The data being sent is:

```
$this->isDebug() = bool(false);
$this->postFieldsForOptions($options) =  Array ( [archiveMode] => manual [p2p.preference] => enabled [api_key] => 46118732 )
```

At first I thought it was something related to the time being out of synk, affecting the JWT, [as described in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46235731/opentok-constructor-create-session-fails-when-not-running-venv), but I couldn't solve it according to what was described there.

Can anyone please direct me towards the right solution?

Thanks in advance,

Amit.

Comment: TokBox Developer Evangelist here. Could you share which SDK version you're using?

Comment: 'OPENTOK_SDK_VERSION', '4.0.0')

Comment: Thanks, Amit. Could you please create an issue on the repo so we can investigate further? https://github.com/opentok/OpenTok-PHP-SDK

Answer (score 0):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

If you're using Windows, please follow the instructions mentioned here to see where Guzzle is looking for the certificates and update it as needed. [cURL error 60: SSL certificate: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822686/curl-error-60-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate#)

As mentioned in the linked answers, this is because Guzzle has switched to using PHP libraries audodetect for certificates rather than it's [process](http://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#verify-option).